# Executing find shell command in Scala using sys.process._ returns empty result

Tags: scala

The `find` shell command below returns expected result on my system:

```
➜  ~ find /Users/ihainan/IdeaProjects/ScalaForTheImpatient -name "*.class"
/Users/ihainan/IdeaProjects/ScalaForTheImpatient/src/main/scala/character_8/character_8/Person.class
/Users/ihainan/IdeaProjects/ScalaForTheImpatient/src/main/scala/character_8/character_8/SecretAgent.class
```

But when I execute the following scala source code, it returns empty result on the same machine:

```
object Ex9 {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import sys.process._
    val classFiles = s"""find /Users/ihainan/IdeaProjects/ScalaForTheImpatient -name "*.class" """ !!

    println(classFiles)
  }
}
```

Scala Version: 2.11.5, System: macOS Sierra, JRE Version: 1.8.0_91

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With postfix `!!` simple commands as `echo ""` will work

```
scala> "echo prayagupd" !!
res6: String =
"prayagupd
"
```

For `find` as well, you can achieve it (removing multiline string `""" """` to string `""`),

```
scala> "find /Users/ihainan/IdeaProjects/ScalaForTheImpatient -name *.class"!!
```

But it could be safer to use `Seq("bash", "-c", "your command")`

eg.

```
scala> import sys.process._
import sys.process._

scala> Seq("bash", "-c", "find /Users/ihainan/IdeaProjects/ScalaForTheImpatient -name *.class")!!
```

which is equivalent to running following bash command,

```
bash -c "find /Users/ihainan/IdeaProjects/ScalaForTheImpatient -name *.class"
```